# controllers not available error appeared in codeigniter

Tags: php

my code is as

```
       <?php
          class HelloWorld extends controller{
          function HelloWorld(){
          parent::controller();
          }
          function index(){
          $this -> load ->view ('index_view');
          }
          }
          ?>
```

and the corresponding error message is as:

```
 ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'controller' not found in 
 C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\helloworld.php on line 2 Call Stack #  
 Time   Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0012  385952  {main}( )    
 ..\index.php:0 2   0.0040  458984  require_once( 
 C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\system\core\CodeIgnit
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html), controllers should be extended with the following syntax using **"CI_Controller"**:

```
class HelloWorld extends CI_Controller {

      function HelloWorld(){
          parent::controller();
      }

      function index(){
          $this -> load ->view ('index_view');
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In any version before 2, `Controller` is the base controller class (which you would extend with `your_controllername`). In version 2 and up, you need to extend `CI_Controller` as this is the new name for the base controller class.

Change the first line to:

```
class HelloWorld extends CI_controller{
```

Hope this helps!